# how to convert mm/dd/yyyy format to dd/mm/yyyy in c#

Tags: c#, datetime

i want to show date time in dd/M/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt, but im getting error -

> System.FormatException: 'String was not recognized as a valid
>   DateTime.'

sample data 
12/14/2018 8:11:30 PM

Expected op
14/12/2018 8:11:30 PM

C# code

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(data.updatedDate.ToString(), "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                string time = dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                ViewBag.attendance_time = time;
```

Comment: Use `h:mm:ss` not `hh:mm:ss` format string when parsing date.

Comment: DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("12/14/2018 8:11:30 PM", "MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
   string time = dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Comment: What is the type of `data.updatedDate`?

Comment: datatype - datetime

Comment: @krishnamohanrao Then you only need `string time = data.updatedDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the string format slightly as the string you're using is not valid.  Change `hh` to `h`:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(data.updatedDate.ToString(), "MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

If you're passing a string that can have single digit for month or day then you should use the following:

```
"M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt"
```

If it always has 2 digit for month and date then you can use:

```
"MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt"
```

`hh` means use 2 digits for the hour, `h` means use one (where possible).  You're also setting `tt` which displays `AM/PM` which could be causing the issue when used with `hh`.

EDIT: (From your comments) If `updatedDate` is a `DateTime` object then you can just do:

```
var time = updatedDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: getting error for time - 12/8/2018 12:43:12 PM

Comment: You're using ParseExact... you need to pass the exact format of the date string your passing in.  You should use `"MM/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt"` if the date can be a single digit.

Answer (score 0):

Use h:m:s instead of hh:mm:ss. "hh" means that hour should be written as 2 digit. so it expects 08 instead of 8. same for minutes and seconds.

Comment: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.